# How can I make a database that can be accessed by multiple people running the same program on different computers?

Tags: python, database, cloud

I am looking to create a python application that accesses a database. However, people must be able to access this database from different computers and always receive an up to date version. I understand that this would have to be some sort of cloud based database, but I cannot seem to find a an API with python bindings or module that allows me to do this. Does anybody know of an API or module that I could use to do this?

Comment: well it depends on the cloud service you use right? how can we suggest you an API if you yourself don't know which cloud service you plan to use?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

you can try with Google Cloud Datastore and App Engine DataStore which are fulfil your requirements:
https://developers.google.com/datastore/ https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

And for api you can use [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/remoteapi?csw=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use **AWS**, you can use Amazon RDS for database and Elastic Beanstalk for deploying your python application on cloud.

This link provides you information how to implement the database part on AWS [Adding an Amazon RDS DB Instance to Your Python Application Environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-rds.html)

If you want to use **Microsoft Azure** then you can refer to the following links

[Azure SQL Database libraries for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/sql?view=azure-python)

[Use Python to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-python)